# Java When using Process#start(), IOException is thrown

Tags: java, ioexception, processbuilder

I want to convert .dvi to .pdf, using dvipdfmx command on Java. But my code throws IOException.
I use OS X.

The following is Main.java.

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
         pb.command("dvipdfmx", "myreport.dvi");
         Process process = pb.start();
         process.waitFor();
     }  
}
```

Please tell me how to solve the problem.

The following is output of error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dvipdfmx": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: Trace would be helpful. In case the file is not found it does not throw any Exception.

Comment: I edited and added output of errors.

Comment: Try it with the absolute path to the executable.

Comment: I tried pb.command("dvipdfmx", "/Users/Jimmy/Documents/workspace/DviPdfMxGui/myreport.dvi"); But the same error occured

Comment: try with "/usr/bin/dvipdfmx" (adjust to the path on your box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chrylis has said in his comment, you should pass the absolute path to **the executable** (not only to the arg):

```
pb.command("/path/to/your/dvipdfmx", "/path/to/your/myreport.dvi");
```